# Attempting to reference a deleted function (No reference to a funciton made)

Tags: c++, function, reference

I'm experiencing a problem at the moment where apparently I am `Attempting to reference a deleted function`. As far as I can see, I'm not actually referencing a function but a smart pointer to a struct.

This is a university project whereupon multiple header files and CPP files are being used to allow us to understand how to use multiple files in the same project and link them together along with understanding and making use of polymorphism. We are using multiple files as the brief states we must. The files and definitions were provided for us.

The following is supposed to conduct a "Breadth-first" search on a terrain map (array of numbers ranging from 0-3) from a starting location to the goal location. It is about path-finding.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include "SearchBreadthfirst.h" // Declaration of this class
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

bool CSearchBreadthFirst::FindPath(TerrainMap& terrain, unique_ptr<SNode> start, unique_ptr<SNode> goal, NodeList& path)
{
    // Initialise Lists
    NodeList closedList;    // Closed list of nodes
    NodeList openList;      // Open list of nodes
    unique_ptr<SNode>currentNode(new SNode);    // Allows the current node to be stored
    unique_ptr<SNode>nextNode(new SNode);       // Allows the next nodes to be stored in the open list

    // Boolean Variables
    bool goalFound = false; // Returns true when the goal is found

    // Start Search
    openList.push_front(move(start)); // Push the start node onto the open list

    // If there is data in the open list and the goal hasn't ben found
    while (!openList.empty() || goalFound == false)
    {
        cout << endl << "Open list front:" << openList.front() << endl;
        currentNode->x = openList.front()->x;
        currentNode->y = openList.front()->y;
        currentNode->score = openList.front()->score;
        currentNode->parent = openList.front()->parent;
    }
}
```

It's highlighting this line: `currentNode->x = openList.front()->x;` as the problem.

The `NodeList` type is defined in `SearchBreadthfirst.h` as the following:

`using NodeList = deque<unique_ptr<SNode>>;`

`SNode` is also defined in `SearchBreadthfirst.h` as such:

```
struct SNode
{
  int x;             // x coordinate
  int y;             // y coordinate
  int score;         // used in more complex algorithms
  SNode* parent = 0; // note use of raw pointer here
};
```

The program breaks upon build. I've been trying to wrap my head around this for days now, so any help is greatly appreciated. If I've missed anything out, let me know and I'll add it in!

James

Comment: For a start, `CSearchBreadthFirst`, `TerrainMap`, and `unique_ptr` are undefined.

Comment: Apologies, they are defined in another header file. My bad

Comment: Why do you have multiple files? Please prepare a [mcve].

Comment: @melpomene Apologies. I have updated the question. It is a university project and these files were given to us to utilise. It is part of the brief that we use them.

Comment: First epistolary SO question I read. A real pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

The error message `Attempting to reference a deleted function` is due to the fact that `std::unique_ptr` explicitly `delete`s its copy constructor because, obviously, there's only supposed to be one copy of the pointer it contains.

When you call

```
openList.push_front(start);
```

You're creating a copy of `start` which is of type `unique_ptr<SNode>` and it has a deleted copy constructor. In order to use a `std::unique_ptr` with a container, you need to move the object into the container. You need to do something like this:

```
openList.push_front(move(start));
```

That will move `start` into the `deque` and move what was in there into `start`.

Comment: I had previously tried this, the same error still occurs

Comment: I just compiled it locally and that fixed the error for me. I do get a *different* error though, on the `cout` line. That's because there's no `operator<<()` for the `SNode` type. You need to either write one or print it out a different way, such as manually printing each field.

Comment: Strange. I actually used `move()` initially but because it didn't work I tried it without. The error on the `cout` line I understand and I'll get to that once this bit works. Very odd though

Comment: It seems that passing a `unique_ptr` by value to the function would generate the same error, would it not?

Comment: Yes, it would. You need to send in a `const unique_ptr<foo>&` instead. (Or non-const if you're going to modify it, I suppose.)

Comment: @JamesEaston Interestingly, if I fix the error on the `cout` line, the error on the line you point out comes back. So perhaps it doesn't work? Let me see what else I can dig up.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. I had updated  the method  signature to use a `const unique_ptr<>` for `start` and that was the issue. Making it non-const again, fixed the problem.